# How do I store an URL in the parse database and pass on to a webview in android?

Tags: android, database, url, parse-platform, webview

I want to store an URL in parse database and pass on to a webview in android. So I have to just store an URL and extract it and do webview.load(url)

But how do I store and retrieve URLs to and from Parse?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it using `String`

```
String urlToStore="www.someurl.com";
ParseObject parseObject= new ParseObject("ClassName");
parseObject.put("url", urlToStore);
parseObject.saveInBackground();
```

**Retrieving**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
     String url_received=  object.getString("url");
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a life saver! :-D

Just one question, should I store my url  in place of "www.someurl.com" or "url" ?

Comment: www.someurl.com, i.e value of your url